# Angular + Google charts : ng-model not updating

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I have a simple google chart and embedded with Angular. The chart gets displayed, implies im able to bind data from angular to googlechart. However the problem is, if i edit a value in array (chart data source) chart is not getting updated.

Code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller("myCnt", function ($scope) {
            $scope.dataArray = [
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 1],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ];

            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
                data.addRows($scope.dataArray);

                // Set chart options
                var options = {
                    'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                    'width': 400,
                    'height': 300
                };

                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCnt">
    <input type="text" ng-model="dataArray[0][1]" /><br />
    <span ng-bind="dataArray[0][1]"></span>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:**
Values of first array are edited through a text box in HTML. Im sure the edit is reflecting, as i can see the span element displaying updated value. Somehow the same value is not getting bind to the chart.

Do i need to load the chart again by calling chart.draw(data, options); If yes, then where should i be calling?

Thank you

Comment: How are you editing that charts array ? manually or through some interface on html page ? Looks like your are doing it manually because i cannot see any way to change data arrays value on page . But i tried your example by manually changing values in your charts array, and it worked fine . The chart presentation changed according to the values . Which browser are you using ?

Comment: @codechat : "Edit 1" section of my question should help. To elaborate, if you run the code in browser you can find a text box which binds to first element's value, which is the data source of chart. You can edit the value from text box and it reflects in the span item below textbox. So angular is working. But somehow its not updating the chart.

Comment: Google charts don't actually "bind" to the data. By that I mean the chart doesn't redraw when the data changes. You'll need to watch the values and trigger a redraw yourself, or give [Angular Google Chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/) a try.

Comment: Wow @nbering didn't knew Angular JS had a Google Charts Wrapper

Comment: @nbering : Thanks for your help. For time being i have opted for the first option of trigger to reload the chart when values have changed. I will explore more on Angular Google Chart. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Seems like google charts don't perform any two way data binding as of today. Based on suggestion from @nbering, i have updated the value outside function and reloaded the chart. Now it seems all good. Its pretty simple, but just for reference, below is the edited code.

```
<html>  
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });

        function display(val) {
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(Mydisplay);
        }

        function Mydisplay() {
            var LocalarData = [
             ['Mushrooms', 3],
             ['Onions', 3],
             ['Olives', 3],
             ['Zucchini', 3.5],
             ['Pepperoni', 3.5]
            ];

            LocalarData[2][1] = +document.getElementById('Txt1').value;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows(LocalarData);

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, LocalarData);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="display()" id="Txt1" />
</body>
</html>
```